# Angular 6 display data with HttpClient, RxJS and GroupBy

Tags: json, angular, group-by, rxjs, httpclient

I'm using Ruby on Rails API app for the backend and Angular 6 for the front. this is the json respond I get from the backend:

**loclhost3000/courses.json**

```html
[  
   {  
      id:1,
      title:"Introduction",
      author:"Dana Inbar",
      segments:[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      id:2,
      title:"Master the ELN",
      author:"Dana Inbar",
      segments:[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      id:3,
      title:"Master the Inventory",
      author:"Dana Inbar",
      segments:[  
         {  
            id:1,
            unit_id:1,
            unit_title:"Introduction",
            name:"Lesson 1: Introduction to the inventory module-                                       looking at one collection",
            data:"www.video01.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:2,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Inventory Customisation",
            name:"Lesson 2: Setting up custom collections",
            data:"www.video02.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:3,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Inventory Customisation",
            name:"Lesson 3: Adding a custom field",
            data:"www.video03.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:4,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Inventory Customisation",
            name:"Lesson 4: Creating derived collections",
            data:"www.video04.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:5,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Inventory Customisation",
            name:"Lesson 5: Using repositories",
            data:"www.video05.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:6,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Inventory Customisation",
            name:"Quiz",
            data:"'[ { "            
              question 1":"___",
              "answers":{  
                "1":"____",
                "2":"____",
                "3":"____"
              },
              "correct_answer":"2"
            },
            {  
             "question 2":"___",
               "answers":{  
                "1":"____",
                "2":"____"
             },
              "correct_answer":"1"
             }
            }
           ] ' " 
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

I have Course model which has many Segments, and Segment is Video or Quiz.
I have course-list, course-detail and course-play components.
I have problem with the course-detail and I want the course-detail page to look like that: [course-detail image](https://my.labguru.com/user_assets/65/attachments/81759/large/Screen_Shot_2018-07-01_at_9.57.13.png?1530428247)

I thought I could do functions in course.service which use groupBy with unit_id and unit_title and do two ngFor (or ngFor group) but because I'm new to angular I don't know how is best to implement this.

I'm adding some files from the program which can help:

**./courses/course.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CourseListComponent } from './course-list/course-list.component';
import { CourseDetailComponent } from './course-detail/course-detail.component';
import { CourseService } from './course.service';
import { CoursePlayComponent } from './course-play/course-play.component';

const coursesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent },
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent },
  { path: 'courses/:id/:segment_id', component: CoursePlayComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(
      coursesRoutes
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    CourseListComponent,
    CourseDetailComponent,
    CoursePlayComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    CourseService
  ]
})
export class CourseModule { }
```

**./courses/course**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  course_id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}


export interface ISegment {
  segment_id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
}
```

**./courses/course.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, retry, groupBy, Filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Course } from './course';

// Inject Data from Rails app to Angular app
@Injectable()
export class CourseService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  private url = 'http://localhost:3000/courses';
  private courseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/courses.json';

  // Handle Any Kind of Errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    // A client-side or network error occured. Handle it accordingly.
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    }

    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    else {
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code ${error.status}, ' +
        'body was ${error.error}');
    }

    // return an Observable with a user-facing error error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happend; please try again later.');
  }

  // Get All Courses from Rails API App
  getCourses(): Observable<ICourse[]> {
  const coursesUrl = `${this.url}` + '.json';

  return this.http.get<ICourse[]>(coursesUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  // Get Single Course by id. will 404 if id not found
  getCourse(id: number): Observable<ICourse> {
    const detailUrl = `${this.url}/${id}` + '.json';

    return this.http.get<ICourse[]>(detailUrl)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );

  }
}
```

**./courses/course-detail/course-detail.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Course } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.sass']
})
export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  course: ICourse;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getCourse(id);
    }

   // Get course detail by id
   getCourse(id: number) {
     this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
       course => this.course = course,
       error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }

   onBack(): void {
     this.router.navigate(['/courses']);
   }

}
```

**./courses/course-detail/course-detail.html**

```html
<div id="main" *ngIf="course">
  <div class="row" id="image">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <br>
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="header">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <br>
        <h1>{{course.title}}</h1>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center" id="progress">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-white"></div>
        </div>
        <td>Your Progress</td>
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="body">
      <div class="container">
        <br>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#Curiculum" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Curiculum</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#About" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About this course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Curiculum">
            <h1>Course Overview</h1>
            <br>
            <ul *ngFor="let segment of course.segmentsByUnitId">
              <ul>
                <li id="title">Unit {{segment.unit_id}}: {{segment.unit_title}}</li>
                <li>{{segment.name}}</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="About">
            <h1>Course Topics:</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**./courses/course-detail/course-detail.sass**

```css
$color: #FFFFFF
$bg-col:  #5c0099
$prog-size: 10px

#image
  background-color: $bg-col
  color: $color

#header
  background-color: $bg-col
  color: $color

#body
  background-color: $color
  height: 100vh
  max-width: initial
  display: flex

#title
  font-weight: bold

#progress
  background-color: $bg-col
  color: $color
  font-size: $prog-size

.progress
    height: 10px
    left: 30%

.progress-bar
  width: 10%
  height: 20px
  background-color: transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the below groupby pipes.
GroupBy pipe returns an object of a key/value pair.
https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#groupby

The installation process for ngx-pipes: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#installation

Below is how I implemented it for my data:
My data:

```
tsks = [{
      CompletedFlag: true,
      ProgressFlag: false,
      DueDate:"2014-10-02T13:12:37.027",
      Signup: "2014-10-04T11:51:10.137",
      ObMilestone: 1,
      ObTask: 119,
      AssignedToId: 0,
      Company: "ABC Corp",
      Description: "Lorem Ipsum",
      Favourite: null,
      FirstName: "Libin",
      LastName: "J",
      MilestoneName: "Blue",
      OnboarderStatus: "Live",
      Partner : null
    },
    {
     CompletedFlag: true,
      ProgressFlag: false,
      DueDate:"2014-10-02T13:12:37.027",
      Signup: "2014-10-04T11:51:10.137",
      ObMilestone: 1,
      ObTask: 119,
      AssignedToId: 0,
      Company: "ABC Corp",
      Description: "Lorem Ipsum",
      Favourite: null,
      FirstName: "Libin",
      LastName: "J",
      MilestoneName: "Blue",
      OnboarderStatus: "Live",
      Partner : null
    }];
```

My code to groupby "MilestoneName"

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let task of tsks | groupBy: 'MilestoneName' | pairs">
  <div>Group milestone name: {{task[0]}}</div>

  <div class="row" *ngFor="let t of task[1]">
    <div>Task: {{t.FirstName}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```